# How to create a search form with dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to make a search algorithm with dialogflow that could take any combination of: first name, address, phone number, zip code or city as input to a search algorithm. The user does not need all of them, but we will refine our search with each additional answer until we only have one result. Basically we are trying to identify which customer we are talking to.

How should this type of intent (or set of intents) be structured? We have tried one intent with multiple parameters, but we do not need all of them to be required. We have also written a JavaScript function for fulfillment but how can we communicate back to dialogflow as to whether we need more information?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, keep in mind that Intents reflect what the *user* is saying, and not typically what you're replying with or what other information you need. Slot filling sometimes bends this rule, but only if you have required slots.

Since you don't - you need a different approach.

This can be done with a single intent, although you may find that multiple intents make it easier in some ways. The approach is broadly the same:

- When you ask the question, make sure you set an Outgoing Context with a relatively short lifespan (2-3 is good) to indicate you are collecting user info.
- Create an Intent (or Intents) that have sample phrases that capture the information you need.

  - Some of these will have obvious entity types (phone number and zip code) while others will be more difficult (First name has a system entity type, but it doesn't include all possible first names).
  - You will need to create sample phrases that collect the parameters by themselves, along with phrases that make sense. You're the best judge of this, and you should probably write some sample conversations before you write the phrases.
- In your fulfillment, you'll figure out if you have enough information.

  - If you do, you can reply and clear the Context that was set. (Clearing it is important so Dialogflow doesn't match the information collecting Intent again.)
  - If you do not, you can add the information you have as parameters to the Context so you can save it for later processing, make sure you reset the Context lifespan (so it doesn't expire), and prompt the user for additional information. Again, having a conversation mocked out ahead of time will help here.

Answer (score 3):

[Slot filling](https://dialogflow.com/docs/concepts/slot-filling) is designed for this purpose.

Hope that helps.

Please post more code/details to help answers be more specific.